# How do we achieve the opposite of Laravel validation rule 'exists:table,column'?

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel validation,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'email'          =>  'exists:users,email',
]);
```

implies that the user input email should exist in the `email` field in the `users` table.
I want to make sure that the user input email doesn't exist in the table to avoid duplicate entries. Any neat approach to this?

I want to try something like: **!exists:users,name** but that's invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use "[unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique)" rule `unique:users,email`

Comment: Isn't this still wrong?  If you have one row with the email, it wouldn't throw any errors, right?

Comment: it's just checking the user record(row) with given email. If found returns false.